# Type Recognition Issue in the process of translating OC to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

### My Situation:

I have learnt Swift for a while and Swift is my only language I've learnt for iOS Development, which means I did not learn Objective-C Systematically. I can just read OC Code a little.

And I got a `Type Recognition` problem when I tried to translate a OC project to Swift project.

### Objective-C Code:

```
static inline NSRegularExpression * AccountRegularExpression() {
static NSRegularExpression *_accountRegularExpression = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _accountRegularExpression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:AccountRegular options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
});

return _accountRegularExpression;
}
```

I confused with those mysterious code.

### My Problem:

- For now, I just met two different things in swift and OC, almost are `variable instance` and `function`, which means I can read and write the code to initial a variable instance and crate the function. But I never seen the thing like that in OC (Yep, I am a beginner...), it is not look like variable instance or method.
- Before asked the question here, I tried to write a swift function to serve as the part like the original one. The thing is, complier did not thrown any error after I built the project.

Here is my Swift Code:

```
func AccountRegularExpression() -> NSRegularExpression {
    var accountRegularExpression: NSRegularExpression!
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, {
        accountRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: self.AccountRegular, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    })
    return accountRegularExpression
}
```

- I have no idea whether this Swift code have the same function like that OC code.

### My Question:

- Can you tell me is that OC code a variable instance? I think it's not a function or method.
- I Google the key word, `inline`, which is the process for anti-compiling. Is this process still work in the Swift?
- How to translate that OC code in Swift in the right way, I guess my swift code is not correct.

A big appreciation for your guide and time.

Ethan Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation is wrong because the variables `_accountRegularExpression` and `onceToken` are declared `static` in C, which for local variables means that its state is kept between function invocations, for the whole lifetime of the program, similar to global variables.

That they are `static` is essential for the correct functioning of this function, which is to return a singleton instance. If they are not `static`, then:

- `dispatch_once` requires that you give it a pointer to a `dispatch_once` that is "stored in global or static scope". By giving it a local variable with automatic storage, you are invoking undefined behavior. It's impossible to know whether it will execute it once or more than once.
- If `_accountRegularExpression` is not `static`, then that means this function cannot remember and return the same instance that it created before. Therefore, it is not a "singleton". If the `dispatch_once` only executes once, then on the second and subsequent time this function will return `nil`. If the `dispatch_once` executes more than once, then every time it executes again it will return a new independent instance. Under no situation does it return an instance that has been returned before.

To make it function correctly in Swift, one way is to make those variables global:

```
var accountRegularExpression: NSRegularExpression!
var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
func AccountRegularExpression() -> NSRegularExpression {
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, {
        accountRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: self.AccountRegular, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    })
    return accountRegularExpression
}
```

However, a better way for the function to return a singleton in Swift would be something like:

```
func AccountRegularExpression() -> NSRegularExpression {
    struct Singleton {
        static let sharedInstance = NSRegularExpression(pattern: self.AccountRegular, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    }
    return Singleton.sharedInstance
}
```

Or just get rid of the function and make it a computed property:

```
var accountRegularExpression : NSRegularExpression {
    struct Singleton {
        static let sharedInstance = NSRegularExpression(pattern: self.AccountRegular, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
    }
    return Singleton.sharedInstance
}
```

Or if this makes sense inside some class, then just put it directly as a static property of the class:

```
// inside some class
static let accountRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: self.AccountRegular, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It looks right, it is a function taking an argument of a function.

You are confused by block syntax in Objective-C, and closure (basically the same thing) syntax in Swift.  Read the function / closure section in the swift language docs, and refer to this pages:

- http://fuckingblocksyntax.com
- http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean that OC code is a `Block` ?

Comment: Yeah, they are called blocks in Obj-C (be glad you missed it), and closures in all other modern languages.  "Closures" because they capture or enclose the scope around them, which makes them very useful.  Read the (entire) Apple Swift intro document, it is mostly pretty good and the price of admission.  Here is the section though: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94

Comment: Thanks again for answer. I already did a little research for `block` -> `closures`. And you said that OC code is a block, but my another question is: why the part of that code without `^`? I think the block alway have the `^`!

Comment: The first / outer "thing" is just a  poorly capitalized regular function, is that what you mean?  Also, you should format your code in Xcode before pasting, I think that is part of your confusion.  You are probably confusing "C" functions with blocks though, and "C" functions are different than bolt-on-later Obj-C methods.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly correct translation would be-

```
    class SomeClass
{
    static let regularPatternForRegularAccount = "Some Pattern";

    static let regularExpressionForRegularAccount = NSRegularExpression(pattern:SomeClass.regularPatternForRegularAccount,
                                options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive,
                                error: nil)

}
```

Here, we have made the regular expression a 'static let' and it will be evaluated lazily and only once for the first time it is accessed.  Also look at:

[singletons in swift](https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton)